# I want to know the resulting label for all of the input data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

Learning was carried out using the random forest algorithm. I want to append the results of the input data to the existing input data, how do I do it? In the case of scikit-learn, it provides model evaluation criteria such as accuracy, precision, recall, and f1 score for the result, but I am not sure if there is a function that returns the label of the prediction result like keras. I don't know where to start with the code, so I'll just ask a question.

Comment: Use model.predict(x_test) to get the predicted labels for test set. If you would like the labels for the entire dataset, use model.predict(X) where X is the dataset without labels and before the train_test split. Post the sample code that you had tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, you have something like this when using sklearn:

```py
input_data = pd.read_csv("path/to/data")
features = ["area", "location", "rooms"]
y = input_data["Price"]
X = input_data[features]
train_X, val_X, train_y, val_y = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=1)
model = RandomForest()
model.fit(train_X, train_y)
```

Now your model is trained. As you mentioned you could get different metrics from the model using sklearn on your validation set.
Getting output label from the model means getting predictions(inference):

```py
output_label = model.predict(val_X)
#This is an nd array with the size of val_y
x = pd.DataFrame(val_X,columns=["input"])
x["output_label"] = output_label
```

Or you could use *numpy.concatenate* to append the labels directly to your input data

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll give it a try.